# Capybara cannot select checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I feel like I have tried everything, but I cannot select a checkbox in my application.

I have two checkboxes that look like this. One with 'cheese' and one with 'pickles'. they're auto generated with Rails form_with's `= form.check_box`

```
<input name="foods[]" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off">
<input class="foodCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="cheese" name="food[]" id="food_cheese">
<a target="_blank" href="MyString">cheese</a>
```

Now to my testing. I have tried the following:

1.

```
check('food_cheese')
check('#food_cheese')
```

2. 

```
find("food_cheese").click
find("#food_cheese").click
find("food_cheese", visible: false).click
find("#food_cheese", visible: false).click
```

3. 

```
find(:css, "#food_cheese").set(true)
```

4. 

```
find(:css, "#food_cheese", visible: false).execute_script('this.checked = true')
```

The page finds the checkboxes. I cannot click the label because it is a link. When I do `save_and_open` nothing is selected. How do I select a checkbox?

Comment: save_and_open saves the current state of HTML attributes not property values so you can’t use it to show the current state of checkboxes. Odds are the attempts you made which didn’t raise errors are checking the box correctly

Answer (score -1):

You can use

`find("#food_cheese").execute_script("this.click()")`

or

`page.execute_script("document.querySelector('#food_cheese').click()")`

Comment: These should "never" be used -- Doing that would make the test basically worthless since it sidesteps what a user could actually do.  The reality of this question is that the `check('food_cheese')` used by the OP is 99.9% likely to actually be working but the method the OP is using to see if it's checked is invalid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).